# "Error: Can't resolve 'bufferutil'" during Amplify build with NextJS

Tags: webpack, next.js, aws-amplify

I'm trying to host my NextJS app on Amplify, but when Amplify is attempting to build the app I get an error saying that either the 'bufferutil' or 'utf-8-validate' module cannot be found. Here's an output from when it failed because it couldn't find the bufferutil module:

```
                                 # Starting phase: preBuild
                                 # Executing command: npm ci
2021-09-21T19:44:34.448Z [INFO]: > aws-sdk@2.983.0 postinstall /codebuild/output/src886343224/[my_app_path]/node_modules/aws-sdk
                                 > node scripts/check-node-version.js
2021-09-21T19:44:34.599Z [INFO]: > @apollo/protobufjs@1.2.2 postinstall /codebuild/output/src886343224/[my_app_path]/node_modules/@apollo/protobufjs
                                 > node scripts/postinstall
2021-09-21T19:44:34.653Z [INFO]: > core-js-pure@3.15.2 postinstall /codebuild/output/src886343224/[my_app_path]/node_modules/core-js-pure
                                 > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
2021-09-21T19:44:34.693Z [INFO]: [96mThank you for using core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock/core-js [96m) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library![0m
                                 [96mThe project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: [0m
                                 [96m>[94m https://opencollective.com/core-js [0m
                                 [96m>[94m https://www.patreon.com/zloirock [0m
                                 [96mAlso, the author of core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock [96m) is looking for a good job -)[0m
2021-09-21T19:44:34.876Z [INFO]: added 1308 packages in 12.354s
2021-09-21T19:44:34.887Z [INFO]: # Executing command: mkdir out
2021-09-21T19:44:34.888Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
2021-09-21T19:44:34.889Z [INFO]: # Starting phase: build
                                 # Executing command: npm run build
2021-09-21T19:44:35.060Z [INFO]: > slack-app@0.1.0 build /codebuild/output/src886343224/[my_app_path]
                                 > next build
2021-09-21T19:44:35.694Z [INFO]: info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
2021-09-21T19:44:35.806Z [INFO]: warn  - No build cache found. Please configure build caching for faster rebuilds. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-cache
2021-09-21T19:44:35.830Z [INFO]: Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
2021-09-21T19:44:35.830Z [INFO]: This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
                                 You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
                                 https://nextjs.org/telemetry
2021-09-21T19:44:35.864Z [INFO]: info  - Checking validity of types...
2021-09-21T19:44:37.467Z [INFO]: info  - Creating an optimized production build...
2021-09-21T19:45:14.794Z [INFO]: info  - Compiled successfully
2021-09-21T19:45:14.795Z [INFO]: info  - Collecting page data...
2021-09-21T19:45:16.189Z [INFO]: info  - Generating static pages (0/7)
2021-09-21T19:45:17.372Z [INFO]: info  - Generating static pages (1/7)
2021-09-21T19:45:17.502Z [INFO]: info  - Generating static pages (3/7)
2021-09-21T19:45:17.511Z [INFO]: info  - Generating static pages (5/7)
2021-09-21T19:45:17.588Z [INFO]: info  - Generating static pages (7/7)
2021-09-21T19:45:17.589Z [INFO]: info  - Finalizing page optimization...
2021-09-21T19:45:17.593Z [INFO]: 
2021-09-21T19:45:17.603Z [INFO]: Page                                Size     First Load JS
                                 ┌ ● /                               1.46 kB         234 kB
                                 ├   /_app                           0 B             230 kB
                                 ├ ○ /404                            1.36 kB         231 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/graphql                    0 B             230 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/slack/redirect             0 B             230 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/test                       0 B             230 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/user/workspaces            0 B             230 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/workspace                  0 B             230 kB
                                 ├ λ /dashboard                      2.73 kB         240 kB
                                 ├ ● /dashboard/search               47.3 kB         285 kB
                                 ├ ● /dashboard/share_of_voice       12.2 kB         250 kB
                                 ├   └ css/6b915c1b3977da366ff4.css  1.53 kB
                                 ├ ● /dashboard/word_cloud           48.1 kB         286 kB
                                 └ ● /sign_out                       1.49 kB         234 kB
                                 + First Load JS shared by all       230 kB
                                 ├ chunks/framework.2191d1.js      42.4 kB
                                 ├ chunks/main.588261.js           20.3 kB
                                 ├ chunks/pages/_app.ba1cc2.js     166 kB
                                 ├ chunks/webpack.307141.js        898 B
                                 └ css/11662bea7c6682700e19.css    4.1 kB
2021-09-21T19:45:17.604Z [INFO]: λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
                                 ○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
                                 ●  (SSG)     automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)
                                 (ISR)     incremental static regeneration (uses revalidate in getStaticProps)
2021-09-21T19:45:17.760Z [INFO]: Starting SSR Build...
2021-09-21T19:46:57.093Z [ERROR]: Error: Command failed with exit code 1: node_modules/.bin/next build
                                  Failed to compile.
                                  ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bufferutil' in '/codebuild/output/src886343224/[my_app_path]/node_modules/ws/lib'
                                  > Build error occurred
                                  Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
                                  at /codebuild/output/src886343224/[my_app_path]/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:15:924
                                  at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/codebuild/output/src886343224/[my_app_path]/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:6:584)
                                  info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
                                  info  - Checking validity of types...
                                  info  - Creating an optimized production build...
                                  at makeError (/root/.//node_modules/execa/lib/error.js:60:11)
                                  at handlePromise (/root/.//node_modules/execa/index.js:118:26)
                                  at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
                                  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
                                  at async Builder.build (/root/.//node_modules/@sls-next/lambda-at-edge/dist/build.js:348:13) {
                                  shortMessage: 'Command failed with exit code 1: node_modules/.bin/next build',
                                  command: 'node_modules/.bin/next build',
                                  escapedCommand: '"node_modules/.bin/next" build',
                                  exitCode: 1,
                                  signal: undefined,
                                  signalDescription: undefined,
                                  stdout: 'info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5\n' +
                                  'info  - Checking validity of types...\n' +
                                  'info  - Creating an optimized production build...',
                                  stderr: 'Failed to compile.\n' +
                                  '\n' +
                                  "ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bufferutil' in '/codebuild/output/src886343224/[my_app_path]/node_modules/ws/lib'\n" +
                                  '\n' +
                                  '\n' +
                                  '> Build error occurred\n' +
                                  'Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors\n' +
                                  '    at /codebuild/output/src886343224/[my_app_path]/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:15:924\n' +
                                  '    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/codebuild/output/src886343224/[my_app_path]/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:6:584)',
                                  failed: true,
                                  timedOut: false,
                                  isCanceled: false,
                                  killed: false
                                  }
2021-09-21T19:46:57.095Z [ERROR]: [G[?25h[G[J
                                  77s › dep5aop5dy2y4 › Error: Command failed with exit code 1: node_modules/.bin/next build
                                  Failed to compile.
                                  ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bufferutil' in '/codebuild/output/src886343224/[my_app_path]/node_modules/ws/lib'
                                  > Build error occurred
                                  Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
                                  at /codebuild/output/src886343224/[my_app_path]/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:15:924
                                  at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/codebuild/output/src886343224/[my_app_path]/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:6:584)
                                  info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
                                  info  - Checking validity of types...
                                  info  - Creating an optimized production build...
                                  [G[?25h
Terminating logging...
```

I've read some people saying that I need to add some externals to the webpack config and I did but still get the same errors:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    Object.assign(config.externals, {
      bufferutil: 'bufferutil',
      'utf-8-validate': 'utf-8-validate',
    });
    
    return config;
  },
};
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "author": "",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "dev:local": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.4.7",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^1.2.11",
    "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "^3.29.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.6",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.0",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
    "apollo-server-micro": "^2.25.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.1",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.2.5",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.983.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "dynamoose": "^2.8.1",
    "graphql": "^15.5.1",
    "micro": "^9.3.4",
    "next": "^11.0.1",
    "next-connect": "^0.10.1",
    "postcss": "^8.3.6",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-content-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-minimal-pie-chart": "^8.2.0",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.6.5",
    "react-wordcloud": "^1.2.7",
    "sentiment": "^5.0.2",
    "stopword": "^1.0.11",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.7",
    "eslint": "7.30.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.0.1"
  }
}
```

Here is my Amplify.yaml file:

```
version: 1
applications:
  - backend:
      phases:
        build:
          commands:
            - '# Execute Amplify CLI with the helper script'
            - amplifyPush --simple
    frontend:
      phases:
        preBuild:
          commands:
            - npm ci
            - mkdir out
        build:
          commands:
            - npm run build
      artifacts:
        baseDirectory: out
        files:
          - '**/*'
      cache:
        paths:
          - node_modules/**/*
    appRoot: slack-app
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

**EDIT**
I just wanted to clarify that I am able to run the build command just fine locally

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi Dom, did you find a solution?

Comment: Solution that worked for me: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/44273